# Determine current Angular 2.x version

Tags: angular

In Angular 1.x you can determine the current version in runtime using
`angular.version`.

Is there anything similar in angular 2.x? I have searched the `ng`, `ng.core`, `ng.common` and `ng.compiler` objects without any luck.

Comment: Maybe have a look inside `@angular/upgrade` module. Something like this could be there.

Comment: Thx @Martin, but unfontunately it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/e628b66cca623bb86e5350d60654cdbb51ae35db) included in Angular 2.3.0-rc0 and up, you can use the `VERSION` const from `@angular/core`.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'angular-version',
  template: '<p>Version: {{version}}</p>'
})
export class VersionComponent {
  version: string = VERSION.full;
}
```

[Live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/vVDcOY/)

If you just need to get the version in the dev tools, try something like

```
document.querySelector('[ng-version]').getAttribute('ng-version')
```

or inspect the `app-root` element.